# Unable to call GWT-RPC from client side application

Tags: java, gwt-rpc

Iam completely new gwt-rpc. I have read few documentation, but not clear at one point. Iam going to describe it.

My client side build is going to implement gwt-rpc to call the server side servlets to access the data. So, do i need to implement server side RPC too?

Means, will client side gwt-rpc will communicate with server side RPC, and that server side rpc will communicate with the servlets? or directly client side gwt-rpc will communicate with servlets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to implement server side RPC too.

You have to build a Servlet in your server side, which must extends the class com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet and implements your RPC interface. You have to register this new Servlet which you have implemented in your web.xml. For example.

Your new Servlet:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class MyServerSideRPC extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyRpcInterface{
   @Override
   public String myRpcMethod(....)  {
    //Do RPC method work
   }

}
```

Your RPC interface which is implemented by your new Servlet

```
 @RemoteServiceRelativePath("service/myrpcpath")
 public interface MyRpcInterface extends RemoteService{
  public String myRpcMethod(....);
 }
```

And in your web.xml on your server side, register the servlet you have created,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServerSideRPC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>.....MyServerSideRPC</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServerSideRPC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtrpc/service/myrpcpath</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as a beginner, iam bit confused. Does, server side and client side rpc will remain on same machine? means either in client side(suppose mobile application) or in server(in remote machine). And if they reside in different machine, means, client side rpc on client machine and server side rpc on server, then how, client side rpc will be able to call the server side rpc? Do we need to configure server ip address in client side or anything else? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to configure server ip address in client side. Anyway, yes, you have to do some things in client side. I suggest this [GWT-RPC tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_rpc_communication.htm)